# Как спрятать token при запросе к API VK

Tags: php, jquery, json, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

При запросе `$.getJSON` к *VK API* для публикации сообщения на стену группы, в *Firebug* выводится кусок кода, в котором светится и токен и номер группы и передаваемое сообщение. Т. е. каждый, кто получит мой токен сможет выполнить подобный запрос (добавить сообщение в группу или наоборот удалить, т.к. права это позволяют). Как можно обезопасить себя от этого. Уменьшение времени жизни токена не подходит, т.к. он должен оставаться вечным.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-69173875&from_group=1&message=<?php echo(urldecode($message)); ?>&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.16&callback=?', function(resp){
            })
            .done(function( resp ) {
                if (resp.response!=undefined)
             console.log( "JSON Data: " + resp.response.post_id );
            else
                console.log("error");
            });

            </script>
```

Причем сообщения отправляются как с сайта, так и с *localhost*, значит привязка моего сайта к *standalone* приложению имеет смысл только при получении токена, а если токен уже записан (где нибудь в БД), то как тогда его безопасно передавать?

Comment: 1. А как он его получит?
2. Токен всегда передается в открытом для сервера виде. Это - условие для идентификации клиента.

Comment: Fike прав, access_token генерируется для конкретного IP адреса и время жизни у него сравнительно мало. Он для того и генерируется, чтобы не светить логины и пароли пользователей

Comment: Нашел решение.. Сделать запрос через Curl

Comment: https за вас его безопасно передает.. причем тут curl?